# Listening to django channels channel_layer from outside of a consumer

Tags: websocket, redis, listener, django-channels

The docs explain that it is possible to publish to the channel layer from outside of a consumer: https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/channel_layers.html#using-outside-of-consumers
I need to do the opposite. I have a fairly complex python script that reads live data from pubnub, processes it, and pushes it to consumers via groups on the channel_layer. This works fine, but I need consumers to be able to announce their presence to this script so that it can push them data (it currently pushes to the channel layer only when it gets new data from pubnub, which could be every 24 hours).

I've decided to solve this by having the consumers publish to a 'presence' channel on connect. I now need the pubnub source script to listen to this channel.
I've tried adding the below to the script, and it no longer throws errors, but it doesn't actually respond to messages. It successfully joins the channel layer, but the message handler `(receive_json)`, never fires.

```
from channels.generic.websocket import JsonWebsocketConsumer


class channelConsumer(JsonWebsocketConsumer):

    def __init__(self):
        self.channel_name = 'source'
    def join(self):
        async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_add)('presence', self.channel_name)
    def receive_json(self, message):
        print("Presence Detected")
        # do some stuff
```

Further on in the code:

```
global channel_layer
channel_layer = get_channel_layer()

global listener
listener = channelConsumer()
listener.join()
```

As I said, there are no explicit errors, it just doesn't ever seem to trigger receive_json. There are definitely packets being published to 'presence', so the issue is definitely in the code below.

Comment: This sounds like a PubNub question, but no PubNub code was included. I tagged it with `pubnub` in the meantime but you can remove it if you are certain there isn't a PubNub insight needed here.

Comment: @CraigConover I'll remove it, if you don't mind. PubNub is the original source of the data, but the issue here is sending data over the channel layer. The original source could be anything.

Comment: Understood. Just sounded like there was an additional PubNub implementation that was needed. Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

For a consumer to receive a message, that consumer needs to be plugged into a Router. The most common case is to use a URLRouter where the Consumer will receive events from a connection (for example a web socket).

You can use a ChannelNameRouter to create a consumer that will listen on a specific Chanel. For example the consumer could be:

```
from channels.consumer import SyncConsumer
class ChannelConsumer(SyncConsumer):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def post_save(self, event):
        print("POSTSAVE", event)
```

and then on your router definicion

```
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter,ChannelNameRouter
application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    "websocket": TokenAuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter([
            url(r"^.*$", RestConsumer),
        ]),
    ),
    "channel":ChannelNameRouter({
        "signals": ChannelConsumer,
    })

})
```

Now you can send a message to that consumer

```
from channels.layers import get_channel_layer
channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
async_to_sync(channel_layer.send)("signals", {"type": "post.save", "message":"Hello Consumer"})
```

Specifically for your case, you will also need to add the "signals" channel to the group you want to use if you want for multiple channels to receive the message.

Notice that if you use the ChannelNameRouter, you will need to start the workers that will process that.

```
./manage.py runworker signals
```